# pixel to percantage

Tags: jquery

```
drop: function( event, ui)
        {
            draggableDocumentOffset = ui.helper.offset(),
            droppableDocumentOffset = $(this).offset(),  
            left = draggableDocumentOffset.left - droppableDocumentOffset.left,
            top = draggableDocumentOffset.top - droppableDocumentOffset.top; 
        }
```

I am using a div as a droppable area. I want to get the position of the dropped element relative to the div in which it is being dropped.

Comment: If you get the size of the page, can you not work it out mathematically?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$(this)`'s width to get a percentage (I'm not 100% clear on where the percentage should come from, but using the width/height and the x/y coordinates you can calculate a percentage):

```
var percentLeft = (left/$(this).width()) * 100,
    percentTop  = (top/$(this).height()) * 100;
```

Also you seem to be using `.offset()` in a somewhat strange manor. Have you seen `.position()`. It gives the position of the element based on it's `offset parent` rather than the document: http://api.jquery.com/position

### Update

To get the position relative to the `droppable` container you probably only need to use `.position()`:

```
var left = $(this).position().left,
    top  = $(this).position().top,
    percentLeft = (left / [droppable container].width()) * 100,
    precentTop  = (top / [droppable container].height()) * 100;
```

Where `[droppable container]` is a jQuery object with the droppable container selected. The droppable container has to have its `position` set to something other than `static` (the default) for it to be the offset parent of the element.

I'm not very familiar with jQuery UI's draggable/droppable but I hope this helps. If not, perhaps you can use some info in the `event` object to calculate percentage.

Comment: actually what i am doing is i am using a div in which elements can be dropped. what i want is that when i drop the element in the div i should get the position relative to the div in which it is being dropped

Comment: @asadrana I **updated** my answer, but I'm not too familiar with jQuery UI's draggable/droppable so I'm not 100% sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Some mathematic will do the job :

```
positionPercent = (positionPixel / containerPixelWidth) * 100
```

Then, in your case :

```
positionPercentLeft = Math.round(left/$(this).width()*100),
positionPercentTop  = Math.round(top/$(this).height()*100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the pixels to a percentage of the drop div. In the case of your code, you could add:

```
 div_width =  //width of drop div can use .css() or .width()
 div_height = // height of drop div can use .css() or .height()

 div_left = //left position of div can use .offset()
 div_top = //top postion of div can use .offset()   

 left_percent = ((left - div_left )/div_width) * 100;
 top_percent = ((top - div_top)/div_height) * 100;
```

Edit: Updated for change in question. This works if the element being dropped is contained by the area. I believe there is a callback for this event.

Answer (score 0):

With the height and the width of the droppable item you can calculate the percentage:

```
w=$(this).width();
h=w=$(this).height();
left_percentage=(left*100)/w;
top_percentage=(top *100)/h;
```